# Loop on a wordpress Page instead of content coming from the WP text editor

Tags: php, functions, loop, templates, page-template

I have created a page template:

```
<?php /* Template Name: homedefault */ ?>
```

But Instead of text coming from here i.e. wp editor:

[image]

I want it to come from the loop:

```
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content','home'); ?>        
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But the loop doesn't seem to be working. Is it possible at all?

P.S. → loop is for the posts →

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the `home.php` template?

Comment: Yes, and the home.php(and front-page.php) template is working fine with no issues, but I am creating them for some other purpose.

Comment: Someone have downvoted me? May I know the reason why the post is downvoted.

Comment: even moderators don't know who downvoted, but nobody is obligated to explain, it would be better to ask on the meta site why a question would be downvoted and how to improve it

Comment: @Tom J Nowell, Thanks. But the people who are downvoting if they can let us know why they are downvoting then it will be much easier for me to update the question. I have read the meta points before look like I am not breaching anything.

Comment: That's what the meta site is for, comments are for clarifying questions, by trying to discuss downvoting here you're hurting your own question and derailing. **If you insist on it you must use the meta site**, that is where discussion of the site and how to improve questions takes place. Not here. What you're asking could even be grounds for downvoting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your custom page template, the default loop is working and that's why the loop is fetching content from the page. You need a custom query in this case. Here's the code.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', 'home' ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Okies thanks for the input. Let me try that query I will update you.

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted the answer. Now I will remember how to generate post loop on a static page. All the best for your WP journey.

Comment: Is it you who have downvoted me?

Comment: You accepted my answer and I got 3 upvotes and 1 upvote in a comment, then why would I downvote someone who helped me to get all these! I didn't do that man -_-